# how to access form control value separately

Tags: angular

I am trying do bi directional Binding and access the form Value in HTML.
When I print the value of the form, it prints successfully.
But When I want to print the value of individual control, it gives error

This is fine

```
{{ModelForm.value | json }}
```

But This gives error :

```
{{ModelForm.firstName | json }}
```

Code is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-je5scu

Comment: Try like {{fname}} and {{sname}} in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it using `{{ModelForm.value.firstName | json }}`

I have modified it in your code- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yqtpvk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

values will print all the control values of a particular form group as an object

to print individual controls use

```
Form.get(controlname).value
```

in your case, it should be

```
ModelForm.get('firstName').value
```

Comment: Faizal, It gives error : Property 'get' does not exist on type 'NgForm'.

But Janeer's Solution worked : {{ModelForm.value.firstName | json }}